# GetRolesAsync exits without a trace

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-server-side

It is a Blazor Server app. I use Serilog but no info is shown. I would expect an exception somewhere, but the code just exists without a trace.

This is a simplified version of what I am trying to do. It exits randomly at any of the two GetRolesAsync:

```
// Both injected as Scoped at Startup.cs
private UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
private RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

public Task<IdentityUser> FetchIdentityUser()
{
    // Two users:
    var allUsers = _userManager.Users.ToList();
    
    // Two roles:
    var allRoles = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();
    
    // Each user is attached to a single role in the db
    // (checked via MysqlWorkbench)

    var roleNames1 = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(allUsers.First()).Result; // <-- sometimes it exits here (no exception is thrown, no trace of what's going on ...)
    var roleNames2 = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(allUsers.Last()).Result; // <-- ...and sometimes it exists here (no exception is thrown, no trace of what's goin on ...)
    
    return Task.FromResult(allUsers.First());
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `FetchIdentityUser()` be async, and then you would `await` those two GetRolesAsync calls? Not sure but that would _appear_ to make a bit more sense here.

Comment: any time you find yourself typing `.Result`, you're probably doing things **very very wrong** (with a caveat around micro-optimizing away state machines for already-completed tasks; if you don't know **exactly** what that means: don't use `.Result`) - you should use `var roleName1 = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(allUsers.First());` (and similar for `roleNames2`) - and mark the method as `async`

Comment: @MarcGravell you are right. Usually when I chose `.Result` is because of the "async creep" (If you’re not careful, it spreads through your code rapidly, and you end up with a mess). e.g.: I've designed a code a certain way, and all the way down my code there's one single function that is awaitable... Thanks for the feedback (and for creating Dapper! ;) which makes db access waaay simpler and intuitive).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are async methods and you need to await them.

*Edit (thanks to Mark Gravell for the comment)*: What you are likely seeing here is a sync-context deadlock as these try to return to the calling thread.  This would also much better explain why you are having difficulty seeing the error!

```
public **async** Task<IdentityUser> FetchIdentityUser()
{
    // Two users:
    var allUsers = _userManager.Users.ToList();
    
    // Two roles:
    var allRoles = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();
    
    // Each user is attached to a single role in the db
    // (checked via MysqlWorkbench)

    var roleNames1 = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(allUsers.First()); // <-- sometimes it exits here (no exception is thrown, no trace of what's going on ...)
    var roleNames2 = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(allUsers.Last()); // <-- ...and sometimes it exists here (no exception is thrown, no trace of what's goin on ...)
    
    return Task.FromResult(allUsers.First());
}
```

You need the awaits and to mark the method itself as async (ensuring it is then awaited where it is called from).

There are very few occasions when you should directly access the Result of a task like this and you would need your code structured explicitly to let this work.

Comment: since `UserManager<TUser>.GetRolsAsync(TUser)` [returns a task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getrolesasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0), there shouldn't be a race condition here - it *should* become blocking; it is more likely to be a sync-context deadlock caused by that blocking (note that what you describe *can* occur in some scenarios involving `ValueTask<T>`, in particular when using `IValueTaskSource<T>`). The fix is still to use `await`, though, so: great!

Comment: Yup, this solved the issue indeed. The thing is that the code in my post was over-simplified (although the problem was identical). In my original code, I was doing this: `allUsers.Select(u => { var roleNames = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(u).Result; ... `, and I wasn't using `await` because I didn't know that I could do this instead: `allUsers.Select(async u => { var roleNames = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(u); ... `, which solved the issue. It is the first time I'm using Identity and I find it difficult to use because of all the things that happen "under the hood".